# Are "in case there are problems" vs. "in case of problems" correct and interchangeable?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, writing-advice

So, I'm giving my phone number to a person so that they can count on me and call me if and when they have problems in the future.

Here are two sentences:

1. Here is my number in case you have problems.
2. Here is my number in case of problems.

Would you say that these two are correct and interchangeable?

Personally, I'm leaning more towards (1), but, perhaps, I'm overthinking.

Comment: There's a slight difference where (1) implies this is for 'you' to use (but not necessarily anyone else).

Comment: The corollary to the point KillingTime has made: **In case of** is the wording you see on small signs in buildings:  *In case of fire, break glass* or "in case of emergency phone 911".  It's *impersonal* advice or instruction to anyone and everyone.

Comment: In such a casual offer, even "Problems? Call me at ..." works. The more formal, the less gracious the offer, when the offer is this little thing.

Comment: These questions are not fit for ELL either.

Comment: @TimR Seen on an English notice in a Japanese hotel: Do not use the lift in case it is on fire.

Comment: @KillingTime I think "you" is implied in (2) as well, unless it's clearly a situation where a group is being addressed. But in that case "you" could be plural as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-case-of) brings out that there are two meanings of 'in case of [problems etc]':

> **in case of something**:
>
> if something happens, or in preparation for when something happens:
>
> - *The camping area has ready access to water, in case of fire.*
> - *A doctor is on call in case of emergencies.*
> - *In case of emergency, please contact the child's parent or guardian.*
> - *In case of disagreement, an independent third party may be called upon.*
> - *This provides increased protection in case of sickness or unemployment.*

A more obvious example where the 'in preparation for when something happens' is forced is

- *Always carry an extinguisher in your car in case of fire (ie in case you have a fire)*.

And one where 'if something occurs' is forced is

- *In case of fire, break glass.* (Clearly not 'break the glass in case you [later] have a fire' sense.)

Obviously, 'Here is my number in case of problems.' has the 'in case you [later] encounter problems' sense.

So either sentence works.

'Break the glass in case you [later] have a fire' wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, sure, but in case there are x is fine too.

Comment: That's not in the question. 'In case there are x is fine too' is a valid comment; 'Yes, sure, but in case there are x is fine too' is patronising.

Comment: Yes, sure, in case there are x, is fine too. At least I mentioned it.